# Why no brackets needed among conditions in if sentence?

Tags: c, if-statement, conditional-statements, logic

```
int num;
scanf("%d", &num);

if (num % 4 == 0 && num%100 != 0 || num % 400 == 0)
    printf("%d", 1);
else
    printf("%d", 0);
```

In this logic, I found I do not need to do `()` in `AND` condition which is in front of `OR` condition.
`if (*(num % 4 == 0 && num%100 != 0)* || num % 400 == 0)`

It's only needed `if (num % 4 == 0 && num%100 != 0 || num % 400 == 0)` without `()` in front of `OR` condition.
so, it seems `(A && B || C)` works like `((A && B) || C)`
but it seemed it could work as `(A && (B || C))` condition.

Why is `()` not needed in this situation? A and B condition are automatically grouped from the beginning?

Comment: When in doubt **use parenthesis**. Remember there is no harm in adding redundant parenthesis to expressions.

Comment: You may check here: [C Operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence)

Comment: See [C11 6.5.3](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.13)

Comment: Contrary to popular belief, most operators on a single line doesn't win a price :) It's considered good practice to always use parenthesis around any complex operand of the && and || operators, even if you know the operator precedence of every operator involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All operators in C (and in fact all languages) have what's called *operator precedence* which dictates which operands are grouped first.

The logical AND operator `&&` has a higher precedence than the logical OR operator `||`, which means that this:

```
A && B || C
```

Is the same as this:

```
(A && B) || C
```

So if you want `B || C` to be grouped together, you need to explicitly add parenthesis, i.e.:

```
A && (B || C)
```

Answer (score 0):

Parentheses decide order of operations, if you move the parentheses around you may change what the output is. In the same way that (A + B) / C is different from A + (B / C) but still a valid equation.

See [Order of Operations in C](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence)

Answer (score 0):

Logical AND has higher priority than OR:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

dg

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).